# How to implement subtraction using only loop and increment

Tags: loops, subtraction

This is an interview question.
We have only two constructs

1. `loop(a)` means loop for a times.
2. `increment(a)` increments a.

Thus to implement a+b one could write

```
loop(a) {inc(b)} 
return b;
```

The question is how to implement a-b.

Comment: Nope. I have tagged interview-questions.

Comment: I think it's impossible; you need a negate or a decrement function

Comment: Presumably you have some comparison functions available also, yes?  If your only constructs really are loop and increment I think it's impossible, but with branching you could make it work.

Comment: I agree the question isn't completely defined. I assume comparison has to be there, no? Besides how do you intend to do it with branching? Is it different from the one I proposed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about;

```
a = 10
b = 8
result = 0

loop(b) {
   last = 0
   times = 0;
   loop(a) {
      last = times
      times = inc(times)
   }
   result = a = last
}

result is 2
```

Js eg;

```
var a = 10;
var b = 8;
var result;

for (var _b = 0; _b < b; _b++) {
    var last = 0, times = 0, loopa = 0;
    for (var _a = 0; _a < a; _a++) {
        last = times;
        times = inc(times);
    }
    result = a = last;
}

function inc(i) {
    return i + 1;
}

print(result) // 2
```

Comment: if a = 2 it prints 0. You need a negate function.

Comment: Aye it will floor negative numbers, but its as close as you can get I think given that there is no negation allowed

Answer (score 3):

I think if break from loop is allowed, a-b can be done in this way:

```
c=0;
loop(a) {
    if (a==b) break;
    inc(c);
    inc(b);
}
return c;
```

Ofcourse assuming a>b.

Comment: but, again, you can only use loop() and inc(). You can't use == operator.

Answer (score 1):

depends if this Numeric architecture is known:

you can take advantage of the "Two Compliment" mechanism of the x86/x64 architecture,

for example, if the signed numbering scheme is cyclic like.

```
f(0 < x < 32768)     = x
f(32769 < x < 65535) = x - 65536
```

Then you can use:

```
dec(a)
{
    loop(65535 [= 2^16-1]) { inc(a) }
}
```

.

solving the riddel as

```
(a-b)
{
   loop(b) { dec(a) }
}
```

Depending on the Signed scheme the addition Constant can change, same for short, long, large integer types.

Hope this is good :)
Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

We're a looking for x, so that a-b = x. In other words a = b+x

Pseudocode

int x = 0

WHILE (x <= a) do {

if (b+x == a) BREAK // satisfies a-b = x

x++

}

Answer (score -1):

```
RESET B
INC B
LOOP A
{
    INC D
    LOOP B
    {
        RESET D
    }
}
```